# How to Find and remove new line in between the record by using spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Sample Input

```
abc^Aabd^Aabe^Aabf^Aabh
abc^A\n
^Aasv^Asaf^Asaf^Asdf
```

Expected output

```
abc^Aabd^Aabe^Aabf^Aabh
abc^Aasv^Asaf^Asaf^Asdf
```

I am trying the above  in spark Scala in shell . The Input structure is 5 columns(no headers), 2 rows and ctrl A delimited. The above input file has a "\n" in middle of the second record I want to remove the \n in middle but not in the **END** .I tried in many ways in spark Scala but doesn't help me .Can any one help in this appreciated

Comment: how do you get the Asdf part in the expected output?

Comment: Sorry that's my mistake . Now I have updated the sample input

Answer (score 0):

Alright, try this:

```
val arr = Array("abc^Aabd^Aabe^Aabf^Aabh", "abc^A\n^Aasv^Asaf^Asaf^Asdf")
arr.map( r => r.replaceAll("\\^A\n"))
```

Comment: note that this assumes an array structure. you might have another collection type but it should work similarly.